# Access JSON data in multi array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I know this question is being asked a lot, but I could not find any case similar to mine.

So I have this array printed out of a JSON response:

```
Array
(
    [contents] => {
    "type": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "previous": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "destination": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "balance": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "work": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "signature": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

)
```

I need to access the "destination" value, but keep getting an "invalid offset" error.
How do I reach it?
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What did you try? Is that the whole response? It's way better if you show us your efforts, that way we can help you figure it out *why* it went wrong, so you can learn how to fix it

Comment: where you need to access these values? backend or frontend?

Comment: is it multidimensional array { i never see this symbol [{] in multidimention array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given above array with key `contents` with some `json` value. First you have to convert that `json` into array. Check below, it might be help you:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'contents' => '{
    "type": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "previous": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "destination": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "balance": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "work": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "signature": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}'
);  

$content = json_decode($array['contents'],true);

echo $content['destination'];
```